# Django Model Form validation failing for FloatField

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a model form; having a field `cost`. I am using `jquery number` on that field that appends commas when the value exceeds 999. 
e.g.

```
Changes 1234 to 1,234
```

When the user submits the form; the data is not validated. 
I try to catch in Clean method, but this value does not exist in self.cleaned_data. 
I also tried to extract that value from the self.data and convert it to 1234 float and append to self.cleaned_data and return. but that didn't work too.

Please let me konw.

```
Cost: Enter a number.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/formatting/

First, set proper locale: settings.USE_I18N, settings.USE_L10N, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE, settings.USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR

Second, set widget to be localized:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
       ...
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['cost'].localize = True
           self.fields['cost'].widget.is_localized = True
```

if you are using `forms.Form` instead of modelform, then you only need to pass `localize=True` argument to your field definition

Edit: while `FormField(localize=True)` and therefore `form.fileds['fieldname'].localize = True` is documented, `widget.is_localized` is not documented and I've taken this directly [from django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.10/django/forms/fields.py#L92). So potentially behaviour may chage in next django versions and so prefered way is using `FormField(localize=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Python can't convert "1,234" string to float.

```
>>> float("1,234")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,234
>>>
```

You can sanitize this data in the form's `__init__` method:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs)
        if data and 'cost' in data:
            data['cost'] = data['cost'].replace(',', '')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I can control it in the clean method or is there any other way? there must be a way to handle it. Not sure what

Comment: In clean i am cleaning it perfectly; and assigning ti to the `cost`. but that is also not working.

Comment: If you do the validation in `clean()` method then you should manually clear the error for `cost` field which is set in the `super(MyForm, self).clean()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the default field like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cost = forms.CharField()

    def clean_cost(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['cost']
        return float(data.replace(',', ''))

    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       field = {'cost', ...}
```

Detailed documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: I have tried that; but i can not get the value in clean_cost.

Comment: i also tried `data['cost'] = float(self.data['cost'])` a dummy number but it didn't work either. not sure why